# GetElementByTagName returns System.Xml.XmlElementList

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an XML document that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<event>
  <name>Test Event</name>
  <date>07/09/1997</date>
  <description>Birthday</description>
  <blogURL></blogURL>
</event>
```

I want to grab these fields and display them in `ASP:Labels`

This is my code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument pressRelease = new XmlDocument();
        pressRelease.Load(Server.MapPath("~/PressSection.xml"));

        XmlNodeList name = pressRelease.GetElementsByTagName("name");
        CurrentEventName.Text = name.ToString();
    }
```

But this is what it displays in the label

```
System.Xml.XmlElementList
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name might suggest and, as [the documentation tells you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk(v=vs.110).aspx), the method returns:

> An XmlNodeList containing a list of all matching nodes. If no nodes match name, the returned collection will be empty.

You need to iterate that list, or simply take the first item if you're sure one will always be there:

```
var names = pressRelease.GetElementsByTagName("name");
CurrentEventName.Text = names[0].Value;
```

That said, LINQ to XML is a far nicer API, I would definitely encourage you to learn more about it:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/PressSection.xml"));
CurrentEventName.Text = (string)doc.Descendants("name").Single();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use Linq to xml. I tried adding this
using 'System.Xml.Linq;'
but it says it does not exist

Comment: @onTheInternet You are also required to be targeting.NET 3.5 or later and have a reference to `System.Xml.Linq.dll` (check the 'references' part of your project tree, you can right-click and add reference if it's missing).

Comment: I'm using LINQ now (the reference was missing. thank you. I thought i had to add it through nuget) and it's easier to follow. Thank you very  much Charles

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/PressSection.xml"));
var query = doc.Descendants("event").Elements("name").FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(query.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the intended behavior.

The reason for it is that it returns a list of all elements that match your criteria. If you know for sure that you'll always want the first element, you could always get the first element by:

```
name[0].ToString()
```

However, you might also want to add some null and empty checking for the XmlElementList as it may also be empty, which will result in you getting a null pointer exception if you try to get an item from it.